# General solution to Laplace Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

Show the general solution to the Laplace equation, $$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial y^2}=0$$
is $\phi(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$.

The only thought I have is let $x+iy$ be $z$, a complex number so $\phi=f(z)+g(z^*)$. What are the next steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asked to show that the general solution to an equation has a particular form, so you should start from the equation. You spotted correctly that it is a good idea to make a change of variables, $$z=x+iy, \qquad \bar{z} = x-iy.$$ By the Chain Rule, you can verify that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = i\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \right).$$ Let me also write $\phi(x,y) = \psi(z, \bar{z})$ for the new function that we want to solve for after making the change of variables. It is an easy calculation to check that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \phi =\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \right) \psi = \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial z^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} + \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial \bar{z}^2},$$ and that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \phi =(i)^2 \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \right) \psi = -\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial z^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} - \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial \bar{z}^2}.$$ So your equation becomes $$4 \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} = 0.$$ Can you see how to finish it off? [Hint: integrate].

Comment: How was this different from mine?

Answer (score 2):

Let's enforce the substitution $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}&=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \bar z}\frac{\partial \bar z}{\partial x}\\\\
&=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \bar z}
\end{align}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z \partial \bar z}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \bar z^2} \tag 1$$

Similarly, for the partial derivative with respect to $y$, we have

$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}=-\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z \partial \bar z}-\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \bar z^2} \tag 2$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain

$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}=4\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z \partial \bar z}=0 \tag 3$$

whereupon solving $(3)$ for $\phi$ reveals that $\phi(z,\bar z) = f(z)+g(\bar z)$.  Finally, substituting back for $z$ and $\bar z$ yields

$$\phi(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$$

as was to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at
$$
\partial_{xx}\phi + \partial_{yy}\phi = \left(\partial_x + i\partial_y\right)\left(\partial_x - i\partial_y\right)\phi = 0
$$
a solution can be any that takes the form of $z = x+iy$ or $\bar{z} = x-iy$ can be used to transform the latter expression as
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z\partial \bar{z}} = 0
$$
which implies a general solution
$$
\phi = F(z) + G(\bar{z})
$$
so taking that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z\partial \bar{z}}\left[ F(z) + G(\bar{z})\right] = \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}}F'(z) + \frac{\partial }{\partial z} G'(\bar{z}) = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

The shortes proof of this is by splitting the operator:
$$ (\delta^2_x + \delta^2_y)\phi = 0 $$ yields
$$ ((\delta_x + i\delta_y)(\delta_x - i\delta_y))\phi = (\delta_x + i\delta_y)((\delta_x - i\delta_y)\phi) = (\delta_x + i\delta_y)f = 0 $$ or, as well
$$ ((\delta_x - i\delta_y)(\delta_x + i\delta_y))\phi = (\delta_x - i\delta_y)((\delta_x + i\delta_y)\phi) = (\delta_x - i\delta_y)g = 0 $$
We must now solve the two transport equations $$ (\delta_x + i\delta_y)f = 0 $$ $$ (\delta_x - i\delta_y)g = 0 $$
Their differential operators are complex scaling-rotators, which means that the transport equations are a left-sense and a right-sense scaling-rotation.
We have thus advantage to rewrite the transport equations in polar coordinates $ (r,\phi) $:
$$ (\delta_x + i\delta_y)f = 0  \quad becomes \quad  (\delta_\phi + i r \delta_r)F = 0  $$
which is solved by any twice differentiatable function $$ F(re^{-i\phi}) $$
and
$$ (\delta_x - i\delta_y)g = 0  \quad becomes \quad  (\delta_\phi - i r \delta_r)G = 0  $$
which is solved by any twice differentiatable function $$ G(re^{i\phi}) $$
The general solution of the Laplace equation is thus
$$ \Phi = F(re^{-i\phi}) + G(re^{i\phi}) $$
i.e. a superposition of forward- and backward-rotating waves; or, in Cartesian coordinates
$$ \phi = f(x + iy) + g(x-iy) $$

QED